# IntelliJ Plugin written in Scala - doesn't work

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

I want to develop my own IntelliJ plugin and I would like to do it using Scala language. When I use Java, everything work perfectly, but I'm not able to run a simple AnAction implemented in Scala.

Have a look at these code samples, I have two AnAction implementations, one in Java and one in Scala, both of them are registered in plugin.xml:

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-5545944-78954/actions.png

If run this plugin, Java Plugin works fine, but unfortunately Scala Plugin doesn't work.

I posted this topic on JetBrains Developer Community, but no one has answered my question yet. Please visit [this topic](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/465468?tstart=0), you would see more screenshots and detailed error code there.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or what I missed, can you please help me? I tried to go through the official intellij-scala plugin configuration, but I can find nothing that would help me, it is so huge.
I think I need a sample code - plugin for IntelliJ written in Scala which is not forked from the intellij-scala plugin. I couldn't find such an example.

Comment: You should include the code samples in code blocks not in a linked png which honestly I'm afraid to click.

Comment: Why not? What's wrong?

Comment: That link is now broken. :-(